# What does "my data has headers" do when importing "from text" to Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, import

When importing text files to Excel, this option doesn't seem to actually affect anything. What is it supposed to do? Is there any documentation that explains it? The official docs [completely ignore it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857).

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data file, the first line can be the text you wish to appear at the top of each column.

For example:

Date, Account Number, Expiration Date, Notes

1/12/18, 0333999, 10/12/18, no comment

more data entries here...

The first line becomes the column header and the remainder of the data is dropped into place below it.

Typically, when one exports data to a CSV file, you would have the headers in the data block being exported.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do, but there have been a number of threads on various forums about the setting being ignored in some cases, which I suspect is the reason for the question.

Comment: Actually, the point is the first line is used anyway, whether you choose yes or no. So what does it matter if you choose yes or no? Maybe does it matter only for printing?